# Display step of square root of an integer in LaTeX

Tags: displaystyle

How to display step of square root of an  integer in LaTeX as follows:

[image]

or

[image]

There is no need to write in Bengali digits. It can be express in 2304, 16   etc

Answer (score 5):

An `array` is a possibility:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{@{}*{8}r@{}}
& & 4 & 70 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80} & 2 & 1 & 6 \\
& & 4 & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & & & \\
\cline{3-5}
4 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & & 70 & & & & \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & & 41 & & & & \\
\cline{3-5}
4 & 2 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{6} & 29 & 80 & & & \\
& & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 25 & 26 & & & \\
\cline{4-5}
& & & 4 & 24 & & & \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```